# I keep getting an error when i use the stem() function to plot the graph, how can I fix this error?

Tags: matlab

```
n=[0:20];   
x=[1 0 1];   
h=2*(3.^n).*(n>=0);   
y=conv(x,h);   
size=length(y);   
a=[0:size];   
p = stem(a, y, 'r', 'filled');  
set(p, 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 4);   
title('y[n]=x[n]*h[n]');   
xlabel('n');   
ylabel('y[n]');
```

This is the error that I get after I run the program:

```
Error in problem4a (line 8)
stem(n,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, all i had to do was change line 6 to the following: 
a=[0:(size-1)];